# CM getting Canonical ID

Tags: java, android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am new to GCM and I don't know how to get the Cannonical Id from the response. This is what I read:

> GCM provides a facility called "canonical registration IDs" to easily
>   recover from these situations. A canonical registration ID is defined
>   to be the ID of the last registration requested by your application.
>   This is the ID that the server should use when sending messages to the
>   device.
>
> If later on you try to send a message using a different registration
>   ID, GCM will process the request as usual, but **it will include the
>   canonical registration ID in the registration_id field of the
>   response**. Make sure to replace the registration ID stored in your
>   server with this canonical ID, as eventually the ID you're using will
>   stop working.

This is my function to send a GCM message to a device from my Server:

```
    private string SendMessageUsingGCM(String sGCMRegistration, string sMessage, string sCollapseKey)
    {
        String GCM_URL = @"https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send";

        bool flag = false;
        string sError = "";
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        sb.AppendFormat("registration_id={0}&collapse_key={1}", sGCMRegistration, sCollapseKey);
        sb.AppendFormat("&time_to_live=30&delay_while_idle=0"); //Para que se reciba cuanto antes
        sb.AppendFormat("&data.msg=" + sMessage);

        string msg = sb.ToString();
        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(GCM_URL);
        req.Method = "POST";
        req.ContentLength = msg.Length;
        req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        req.Headers.Add("Authorization:key=" + sGcmApiKey); //Here goes my Api Key 

        using (StreamWriter oWriter = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            oWriter.Write(msg);
        }

        using (HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse())
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                string respData = sr.ReadToEnd();

                if (resp.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)   // OK = 200
                {
                    if (respData.StartsWith("id="))
                        flag = true;
                    else
                        sError = respData;
                }
                else if (resp.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)   // 500
                    sError = "Internal server error. Try later.";
                else if (resp.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.ServiceUnavailable)    // 503
                    sError = "Server not available temnporatily. Try later.";
                else if (resp.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)          // 401
                    sError = "The API Key is not valid.";
                else
                    sError = "Error: " + resp.StatusCode;
            }
        }

        if (flag == true)
            return "1";

        return "0 " + sError;
    }
```

So, how can I get the canonical registration ID in the registration_id field of the response?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of how the response is parsed by [Sender.java](https://code.google.com/p/gcm/source/browse/gcm-server/src/com/google/android/gcm/server/Sender.java?r=83d8e0238574c6b33c893d9cda3293d1dfca16c1) in `sendNoRetry` method :

```
   try {
      BufferedReader reader =
          new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
      try {
        String line = reader.readLine();

        if (line == null || line.equals("")) {
          throw new IOException("Received empty response from GCM service.");
        }
        String[] responseParts = split(line);
        String token = responseParts[0];
        String value = responseParts[1];
        if (token.equals(TOKEN_MESSAGE_ID)) {
          Builder builder = new Result.Builder().messageId(value);
          // check for canonical registration id
          line = reader.readLine();
          if (line != null) {
            responseParts = split(line);
            token = responseParts[0];
            value = responseParts[1];
            if (token.equals(TOKEN_CANONICAL_REG_ID)) {
              builder.canonicalRegistrationId(value);
            } else {
              logger.warning("Received invalid second line from GCM: " + line);
            }
          }

          Result result = builder.build();
          if (logger.isLoggable(Level.FINE)) {
            logger.fine("Message created succesfully (" + result + ")");
          }
          return result;
        } else if (token.equals(TOKEN_ERROR)) {
          return new Result.Builder().errorCode(value).build();
        } else {
          throw new IOException("Received invalid response from GCM: " + line);
        }
      } finally {
        reader.close();
      }
    } finally {
      conn.disconnect();
    }
```

As you can see, the canonical registration ID is searched for in the second line of the response, but only if the first line of the response contains message ID.

Comment: Sorry. I don't understand. In what part of my code do I have to paste your code?

Comment: @Ton You can't copy it as is, since you are using different classes to process the response from Google. It's just an example. You get your response is `respData` String. You have to check if it contains two lines, and if it does, check if the second line starts with registration_id.

Answer (score 0):

Canonical Id is obtained in the result returned after pushing the notification.

Assuming the message has already been built and you have the registrationId of the device, below is a method to send a GCM message to a single device from my server and get canonical id from response:-

```
private void sendNotificationToSingleDevice(Message message, String registrationId) {

    try {
        //Send a message to a single device 
        Result result = sender.send(message, regtoken, 1);
        String canonicalId = result.getCanonicalRegistrationId();
        // do code to replace existing registration id with the canonical id
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Below is a method to broadcast a message from my server and get canonical id from response:-

```
private void sendNotificationToMultipleDevices(Message message, List<String> registrationIds) {

    try {
        //Send a message to a multiple devices
        MulticastResult result = sender.send(message, registrationIds, 1);
        if (result.getResults() != null) {
            // this for loop loops through the response returned after pushing the message to each device.
            for(int i = 0; i < result.getResults().size(); i++) {
               String canonicalId = result.getResults().get(i).getCanonicalRegistrationId(); 
               // do code to replace existing registration id with the canonical id
            }
        } 
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```